# Breaking Ada privacy for Test functions

Tags: ada

Say I have two packages:

```ada
with Ada.Streams; use Ada.Streams;
package P is
   type SEA is new Stream_Element_Array (1..4);
   function foo (Input : in SEA) return Natural;
private
   type PRecord is record
      Bar : Natural := 0;
   end record;
   function To_PRecord is new Ada.Unchecked_Conversion
     (Source => SEA,
      Target => PRecord);
end P;
------
package body P is
   function foo (Input : in SEA) return Natural
   is
      Tmp : constant PRecord := To_PRecord (Input);
   begin
      return Tmp.Bar;
   end foo;
end P;
```

And

```ada
-- Say SEA was defined in a third package and is accessible
package Q is
   function foo (Input : SEA) return Natural;
end P;
-----
with P;
package body Q is
   function foo (Input : SEA) return Natural
   is
   begin
      return P.foo(Input);
   end foo;
end Q;
```

The Package P is easily testable with:

```ada
with AUnit.Assertions; use AUnit.Assertions;
package body P.Tests is
   function To_SEA is new Ada.Unchecked_Conversion
     (Source => PRecord,
      Target => SEA);

   procedure Test_Foo
   is
      Input : PRecord := (Bar => 42);
   begin
      Assert (foo(To_SEA (Input)) = 42, "foo failed miserably");
   end Test_Foo;
end P.Tests;
```

But how may I test Q? `PRecord` is not accessible. As such, I do not see how Q is testable without changing much the code I am testing. In C++ I would define the package `Q.Tests` as a `friend` of `P` and get access.

I guess I could define `PRecord` in a package that would be withed by `P` and `Q.Tests` but is there a solution that do not require to change P or Q (because I do not really like when I need to change production code for the sake of testing).

Comment: You shouldn't test private functions or state -- they are implementation details and prone to changes that will break your tests. By testing these you are pouring concrete all over your implementation and hampering progress. If you can't get enough information from the public interface then you've either made wrong assumptions about your tests or your application.

Comment: Dear Software Engineer, all I want is unit test legacy code I don't feel at all responsible for. But you know, I feel responsible for the evolution I perform and want to test them :)

Comment: I didn't say that you shouldn't test, of course you should, and your code should pass the test, but you shouldn't test the private parts directly. I said that you should only write tests through the public interface and not directly test the implementation details. You should get enough info through the public interface to test the implementation without having to expose private implementation.

Comment: I fear I cannot gather enough information from the public part of the packages. Or I could try to construct SEA by hand (which the API relies on). But using an unchecked_conversion from the record would be more readable IMHO. One could argue that the record shall be public as it is the spec of the SEA. But it currently isn't. And I'm breaking my head around to not duplicate the record (or the part of it I'm interested in)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A child package `P.Spy` has visibility of the whole of `P`’s spec; `Q.Tests` could call it to do validation checks.

Comment: Dear Simon, however, in `P.Spy` declaring `subtype Bar is P.PRecord;`  leads to `"PRecord" is not a visible entity of "P"`. Is there another way to make PRecord visible?

Answer (score 0):

Based on Simon Wright answer, one can define the `P.Spy` package as follows:

```ada
package P.Spy is
   function Create (Bar : in Natural) return SEA;
private
   function To_SEA is new Ada.Unchecked_Conversion (Source => PRecord,Target => SEA);
end P.Spy;
---
package body P.Spy is
   function Create (Bar : in Natural) return SEA
   is
      Result : PRecord;
   begin 
      Result.Bar := Bar;
      return To_SEA (Result);
   end Create;
end P.Spy;
```

Which allows to give `Q.Tests` ability to test its public interface.

Comment: The first part of this is what I was had in mind. The second part doesn’t work (any more than `subtype Bar is PRecord;` does)

Comment: You're right, the second part did work when I had `type PRecord is private;` which changed the public spec and was not acceptable as a solution. I'll edit my answer.